# Evaluating postfix expressions in java

Tags: java

I have a problem i can't find the wrong in this function it sometimes do well with some inputs but sometimes no for examle this Input "6 2 / 3 – 4  2 * +" can any one help.

```
public static double Evaluating_postfix_expressions(String postfix) throws Exception{
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(postfix);
    int numOF_tokens = st.countTokens();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numOF_tokens; i++) {
        Object term = st.nextToken();
        try { // if it is an operand there is no problem
            float x =  Float.parseFloat((String)term);
            stack.push(x);
        } catch (Exception e) { // it is an operator
            float v1 = (float) stack.pop();
            float v2 = (float) stack.pop();
            switch ((String) term) {
            case "+":
                stack.push(v2 + v1);
                break;
            case "-":
                stack.push(v2 - v1);
                break;
            case "*":
                stack.push(v2 * v1);
                break;
            case "/":
                stack.push(v2 / v1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return (float) stack.pop();
}
```

Comment: Does it work for something like `1 2 +`?

Comment: What is the function supposed to do?

Comment: `$` isn't a valid operator, but it would be caught by the exception.  Run through your code, and trace it to see what it's actually doing.

Comment: Looks to me like there's nothing wrong... then again, I don't know what the code is supposed to do! :)  Could you post a description of your goal, and a description of what's happening when you run the troublesome input?

Comment: Ohh is this an RPN calculator? Why don't you specify in the question?

Comment: @Hassan: it does say _postfix_ in both the title and the function name. (Which makes this one of the best-named functions I've seen lately...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that you've given an incorrect operator as input:

```
6 2 / 3 – 4 2 * +
```

Note the difference with a version hand-typed right here:

```
6 2 / 3 - 4 2 * +
```

You've used a dash instead of a hyphen -- or the other way around:

```
$ echo -n – | xxd
0000000: e280 93                                  ...
$ echo -n - | xxd
0000000: 2d                                       -
$
```

This is part of the problem with a catch-all exception that doesn't report any problems. You should modify your `switch` to report invalid operators, which would have made catching this one significantly easier. (I just happened to think that it *looked funny*.)

Comment: @climbage: Ha! That's an _excellent_ theory. At least I hope you're correct.

Comment: Agree that this is a great example of why catch-all exceptions are bad.